# Make default browser whichever one is currently running?

Tags: macos, mac, browser

I switch back and forth between Firefox, Safari, and WebKit all the time.  When I click a link in Mail, for example, it will use the system's default browser, but I really want to make it use whatever I have running (whether it's Firefox, Safari, or WebKit).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: +1 almost exactly my question. except not just the one currently running, but also the one being used on top. I may have more than 1 running at same time. :)

Comment: FYI, it's also possible to do this on Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20590/set-default-browser-to-open-browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An app actually exists to do this, called [Choosy](http://choosyosx.com/). It costs $12, but does more than just this. For your setup, you would set "When one or more browsers are running…" to "Use best running browser" in the Behavior tab, and add all your browsers to the Browsers tab.

Comment: Just a follow-up, in case anyone's interested:  I've been using Choosy  and it's great!  Does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This also does what I needed as well! +1

Comment: Here's an almost equal alternative: Highbrow http://www.heliumfoot.com/highbrow

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way I can think of (although not the most intelligent) is just to enable the "alert me if not default browser" option on each and simply make it the default each time you start it.

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is writing a shell script that sets the default browser and opens a specific browser, so instead of opening Firefox by using it's icon, you would use your "Start Firefox" shell script that sets the default browser to firefox and then opens firefox.